# query after inner joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables TableA and TableB....

**TableA**

```
+----+-----------------+
| Id |  ColName        |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 |  Name1          |
|  1 |  Name2          |
|  1 |  Name3          |
|  1 |  Name4          |
|  1 |  Name5          |
|  1 |  Name6          |
|  1 |  Name7          |
|  1 |  Name8          |
+----+-----------------+
```

**TableB**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Id |  ColName        | CriticalityName |  RefNo          |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  Low            |  RE1,RE2        |
|  1 |  Name1          |  Low            |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  Low            |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  Low            |  RE1,RE2        |
|  1 |  Name6          |  High           |  RE3            |
|  1 |  Name7          |  High           |  RE3            |
|  1 |  Name8          |  High           |  RE1,RE@,RE3    |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE4,RE5            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name5          |  High           |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name6          |  High           |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE3            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE2            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE4            |
|  1 |  Name3          |  High           |  RE5            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  Low            |  RE1            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  Low            |  RE1,RE@,RE3    |
|  1 |  Name1          |  High           |  RE5            |
|  1 |  Name1          |  Low            |  RE1,RE@,RE3    |
|  1 |  Name8          |  Low            |  RE4            |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I need to filter using **RefNo** column, while inner joining two table TableA,TableB

I need a output as below:

```
    +----+--------------+--------------+
    | Id |  ColName     |  RefNo       |
    +----+--------------+--------------+
    |  1 |  Name1       |   RE1        |
    |  1 |  Name5       |   RE1        |
    |  1 |  Name6       |   RE1        |
    |  1 |  Name8       |   RE1        |  
    +----+--------------+--------------+
```

here i'm inner joining TableA and TableB and filter with RefNo (passing RE1 as parameter).

In which ever row contains RE1, is displayed as output..

I dnt know to filter it after inner joining..

Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.id, a.colname, 'RE1' as b.refno
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.colname = b.colname and
        ',' + RefNo + ',' like '%,' + 'RE1' + ',%' ;
```

As a note:  it is a really, really bad idea to store lists of things in a column.  SQL offers a great data structure for storing lists of things, it is called a table and not a string column.  In this case, you want a junction table, that has a separate row for each individual `id` (and/or `ColName`) and `RefNo`.

Comment: why do we need **',' + RefNo + ',' like '%,' + 'RE1' + ',%'** ? Can't we just use RefNo like '%RE1%'. It will be useful only when we have RE11.

Comment: @NMK . . . I don't understand your comment.  Presumably, the OP wants "RE1" and "RE11" to be counted as different things -- hence the use of delimiters.